# MongoDB: $out grouping the same value

Tags: mongodb

imagine that we have a list of books:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("1"), 
"title" : "Fantasy 1", 
, 
"Characters" : ["Harry Potter", "Voldemort", "Aragorn"

], 
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("2"), 
"title" : "Fantasy 2",  
"Characters" : ["Harry Potter", "Vito Corleone"

],
}
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("3"), 
"title" : "Fantasy Final",  
"Characters" : ["Harry Potter", "Legolas"

], 
}
```

I would like to unwind the characters into a new collection (called "Char"). Then, I would like to group them so the character name is not repeated. Also, I would like to count how many characters there are.

So far I've made this:

```
step1 = {$unwind : "$Characters"}
query1 = {"_id" : 0}
step2 = {$project : query1}
step3 = {$out: "Char"}
steps = [step1, step2, step3]
db.movies.aggregate(steps)

db.Char.distinct("Characters").length
```

I don't know if, so far, I'm doing it good. Also, as you can see, I don't know how to group the same characters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need this query:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$Characters"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "characters": {
        "$addToSet": "$Characters"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "size": {
        "$size": "$characters"
      },
      _id: 0
    }
  }
])
```

First of all the query `$unwind` for each character to get all. The `$group` by the field 'Characters' and use `$addToSet` to avoid duplicates.

Then only you need use project to calculate the size.

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/oerMRQQD7oh)